# Производительность пробежки по коллекции

Tags: java, java-8

Подскажите, какой вариант будет производительней?

```
for (Resume resume : listResume) {
        map.put(resume.getId(), resume);
    }
```

Или

```
listResume.forEach((resume) -> {
        map.put(resume.getId(), resume);
    });
```

Comment: Одинаковы будут.

Comment: вангую что примерно одинаково

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для максимально точного ответа нужно знать тип listResume, чтобы сравнивать его реализацию forEach.

Ниже код метода forEach интерфейса Iterable, в зависимости от коллекции, метод может быть переопределен:

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
     Objects.requireNonNull(action);
     for (T t : this) {
         action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

Как видно код практически идентичен классическому перебору в цикле for-each, за исключением проверки значения action на null:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(action);
```

Кроме того в случае forEach() будет создан экземпляр Consumer, соответственно какое-то процессорное время будет на это потрачено.

За исключением этого код выполняется одинаково.